# Matching number versus Independence number in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking at partial functions f:V -> V on a finite graph (undirected no loops or multiple edges) G=(V,E) such that

1) The range f(V) is an independent set of vertices.

2) The "kernel" equivalence relation ~ on the domain of f defined by v~w if f(v)=f(w)is a matching. That is, each partition class has precisely two elements, which is an edge and the collection of partition classes is a matching in G.

Questions:

1) Has anyone run into such functions on a graph?

2) What is the largest rank (number of elements) in the range of such a function?

Obviously it is bounded above by the minimum of the matching number and the independence number of the graph. Can more be said than that.